Ratio of radii in rings of tangential circles


The picture of my table mat above is the inspiration for this problem.
Suppose we have a central circle. Around this central circle we lay a ring of $n$ smaller circles of radius $r$ such that they are tangent to two other smaller circles and also the central circle. We then lay a ring of $n$ larger circles of radius $R$ such that each one is tangent to two smaller circles and two larger circles. This is depicted in the diagram above.
What is the ratio $\frac{R}{r}$ as a function of $n$?

I have solved the problem below but I wonder if there is a quicker way to reach the solution?

Solving the problem
I have indicated the angles on the triangles on the diagram. The expressions for the angles on the diagram are easy to check after realising that the lines connecting the centres of the smaller circles and the lines connecting the centres of the larger circles form regular $n$-sided polygons.
This then leaves us with the results
\begin{equation}
\frac{R}{r+R} = \sin\left(\frac{180}{n}+\theta\right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\frac{r}{r+R} = \sin(\theta)
\end{equation}
Adding these two equations together gives us the equation
\begin{equation}
\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}+\theta\right)+ \sin(\theta) = 1
\end{equation}
Now using the fact that $\sin(\alpha+\beta) = \sin(\alpha)\cos(\beta) + \sin(\beta)\cos(\alpha)$ we have that
\begin{equation}
\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)\cos(\theta)+
\sin(\theta)\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+\sin(\theta) = 1
\end{equation}
$\implies$
\begin{equation}
\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)\cos(\theta)+
\left[\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+1\right]\sin(\theta) = 1
\end{equation}
Now converting to harmonic form, the magnitude will have
\begin{equation}
M = \sqrt{\sin^2\left(\frac{180}{n}\right) +\left[\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+1\right]^2}=\sqrt{2\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+2}
\end{equation}
and shift
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \arctan\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+1}\right)
\end{equation}
So we are required to solve
\begin{equation}
M\sin(\theta+\alpha)=1
\end{equation}
$\implies$
\begin{align}
\theta = \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{M}\right)-\alpha 
\\
\\
= \arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+2}}\right)- \arctan\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+1}\right)
\end{align}
Now dividing equation (1) by equation (2),
\begin{align}
\frac{R}{r} = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}+\theta\right)}{\sin(\theta)} = \frac{1-\sin(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)} = \frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}-1
\\
\\
 = \frac{1}{\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+2}}\right)- \arctan\left(\frac{\sin\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)}{\cos\left(\frac{180}{n}\right)+1}\right)\right)}-1
\end{align}
Simplifying
Let us deal with the denominator. Define $t := \frac{180}{n}$
We know that $\sin(a-b) = \sin(a)\cos(b)-\cos(a)\sin(b)$.
Hence
\begin{align*}
\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}\right)- \arctan\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1}\right)\right) =
\\
\\
= \sin\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}\right)\right]\cos\left[\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1}\right)\right]
\\
\\
- \cos\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}\right)\right]\sin\left[\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1}\right)\right]
\end{align*}
This is split into four parts so let us deal with each part individually.
Clearly
\begin{equation}
\sin\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}
\end{equation}
Now $\cos(\arctan(\gamma)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\gamma^2}}$. So
\begin{align*}
\cos\left[\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)+2\cos(t)+1}+1}}
\\
\\
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2\cos(t)+2}{\cos^2(t)+2\cos(t)+1}}} = \frac{\cos(t)+1}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}
\end{align*}
So we can see here that the answers multiply together to equal $\frac{1}{2}$
Now dealing with the third part. Using the fact that $\cos(\arcsin(\gamma)) = \sqrt{1-\gamma^2}$
\begin{align*}
\cos\left[\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}\right)\right] = \sqrt{\frac{2\cos(t)+1}{2\cos(t)+2}}
\end{align*}
Now dealing with the fourth part. Using the fact that $\sin(\arctan(\gamma)) = \frac{\gamma}{\sqrt{\gamma^2+1}}$ we have that
\begin{align*}
\sin\left[\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1}\right)\right] = \frac{\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{\cos(t)+1}\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{2\cos(t)+2}{\cos^2(t)+2\cos(t)+1}}}=\frac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{2\cos(t)+2}}
\end{align*}
Now multiplying the third and fourth parts together we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sin(t)\sqrt{2\cos(t)+1}}{2\cos(t)+2}
\end{equation}.
So the whole denominator simplifies to:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sin(t)\sqrt{2\cos(t)+1}}{2\cos(t)+2}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{align}
\frac{R}{r} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\cos(t)+1-\sin(t)\sqrt{2\cos(t)+1}}{\cos(t)+1}\right)}-1 
\\
\\
= \frac{2\cos(t)+2}{\cos(t)+1-\sin(t)\sqrt{2\cos(t)+1}}-1
\end{align}
This yields the final simplified result:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\frac{R}{r} = \frac{1+\cos(t)+\sin(t)\sqrt{2\cos(t)+1}}{1+\cos(t)-\sin(t)\sqrt{2\cos(t)+1}}}
\end{equation}
Where $t = \frac{180}{n}$

I had similar idea for calculation but was not patient enough to do that. Good work, +1.

enter image description here

Comment: This is what I found by drawing:
For n=6:
$r_1=23.7, r_2=62.35, \frac {r_2}{r_1}=2.63$
$r_3=161.3, \frac {r_3}{r_2}=2.587$
$r_4=417.6, \frac {r_4}{r_3}=2.588$
For N=12:
$r_1=9, r_2=14.4, \frac {r_2}{r_1}=1.6$
$r_3=23.5, \frac {r_3}{r_2}=1.57$
$r_4=37.2, \frac {r_4}{r_3}=1.58$
It seems the ratio decreases with the increase of N.

I believe I have found the solution now (which I have posted). It matches with your approximations. However, the ratio converges to 1 not the golden ratio.
